# (11db) and output 0 syntax errors

Tags: c

I made this code for a resistor calculator and I keep getting syntax errors like (11db) or an output value of 0. Its 6 am here so maybe I'm overlooking something. Also I think I should mention that I'm using xCode.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_COLOR_STR_LEN 10

int valueFormColor(char const * const color)
{

    if(strcmp("black", color)==0)
        return 0;
    if(strcmp("brown", color)==0)
        return 1;
    if(strcmp("red", color)==0)
        return 2;
    if(strcmp("orange", color)==0)
        return 3;
    if(strcmp("yellow", color)==0)
        return 4;
    if(strcmp("green", color)==0)
        return 5;
    if(strcmp("blue", color)==0)
        return 6;
    if(strcmp("violet", color)==0)
        return 7;
    if(strcmp("gray", color)==0)
        return 8;
    if(strcmp("white", color)==0)
        return 9;
    return 0;
}

int mult(char const * const multiplier)

{
    if(strcmp("black", multiplier)==0)
        return 1;
    if(strcmp("brown", multiplier)==0)
        return 10;
    if(strcmp("red", multiplier)==0)
        return 100;
    if(strcmp("orange", multiplier)==0)
        return 1000;
    if(strcmp("yellow", multiplier)==0)
        return 10000;
    if(strcmp("green", multiplier)==0)
        return 100000;
    if(strcmp("blue", multiplier)==0)
        return 1000000;
    if(strcmp("violet", multiplier)==0)
        return 10000000;
    if(strcmp("gold", multiplier)==0)
        return 0.1;
    if(strcmp("silver", multiplier)==0)
        return 0.01;
    return 0;

}

int tol(char const * const tolerance)

{
    if(strcmp("brown", tolerance)==0)
        return 1;
    if(strcmp("red", tolerance)==0)
        return 2;
    if(strcmp("green", tolerance)==0)
        return 0.5;
    if(strcmp("blue", tolerance)==0)
        return 0.25;
    if(strcmp("violet", tolerance)==0)
        return 0.10;
    if(strcmp("gray", tolerance)==0)
        return 0.05;
    if(strcmp("gold", tolerance)==0)
        return 5;
    if(strcmp("silver", tolerance)==0)
        return 10;
    return 0;
}

int main()

{
    char bands;
    char color1[MAX_COLOR_STR_LEN];
    char color2[MAX_COLOR_STR_LEN];
    char color3[MAX_COLOR_STR_LEN];
    char color4[MAX_COLOR_STR_LEN];
    char color5[MAX_COLOR_STR_LEN];
    char color6[MAX_COLOR_STR_LEN];
    float value;


    printf("Select how many bands the resistor has");
    printf("\nA. 4 bands");
    printf("\nB. 5 bands");
    printf("\nC. 6 bands\n");
    scanf("%c", &bands);

switch(bands)

    {

case 'a':
case 'A':
    printf("Enter the colors in the proper order\n");
    scanf("%s %s %s %s", color1, color2, color3, color4);

    value = (10 * valueFormColor(color1) + valueFormColor(color2)) * mult(color3);
    printf("The total resistance is %.2f with %d%% tolerance\n", value, tol(color4));
    break;

case 'b':
case 'B':
    printf("Enter the colors in the proper order\n");
    scanf("%s %s %s %s %s", color1, color2, color3, color4, color5);

    value = (100 * valueFormColor(color1) + 10 * valueFormColor(color2) + valueFormColor(color3)) * mult(color4);
    printf("The total resistance is %.2f with %d%% tolerance\n", value, tol(color5));
    break;

case 'c':
case 'C':
    printf("Enter the colors in the proper order\n");
    scanf("%s %s %s %s %s %s", color1, color2, color3, color4, color5, color6);

    value = (1000 * valueFormColor(color1) + 100 * valueFormColor(color2) + 10 * valueFormColor(color3) + valueFormColor(color4)) * mult(color5);
    printf("The total resistance is %.2f with %d%% tolerance\n", value, tol(color6));
    break;

    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show us your example input, expected output, and actual output.  And what do you mean by "syntax error"?  Does it even compile?

Comment: return of function if `int` then return 0.5; (return 0 : 0.5 convert  to 0)

Comment: for 4 bands if I were to input red blue brown gold I would expect the output to be 960 total resistance with 5% tolerance, however it just stops the operation and shows (11db). For the 6 band case it gives me 0 no matter the input

Comment: For `"A\n red blue brown gold\n"` the code gives "The total resistance is 260.00 with 5% tolerance". Btw: The result string misses the unit, that is "Ohm".

Comment: For red blue, you should get 26 and not 96. This is also what the program outputs. See also [Resistor color-coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_color_code#Resistor_color-coding)

Comment: sorry yes 26 idk where that 96 came from, and alk, the code is working for you?

Comment: explain "stops the operation and shows (11db)" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in

```
int tol(...)
   ...
   return 0.1


int mult (...)
   ...
   return 0.01
```

You return a const `float` from a function that the compiler rounds up/down - which in your case causes the return for certain cases to give a multiplier of `0`.

---

As I read the comments, this was already noted by @BLUEPIXY

Comment: I did change it when Bluepixy point it out but Im still getting the same errors

Comment: ok I copy paste it into a new folder and this solution is now working, Im not sure why it wouldn't work properly on the original project. Thanks